# Difference between roots of a cubic

Tags: polynomials, roots

Given a cubic polynomial $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$ with three real roots $r_1 \le r_2 \le r_3$, is there a simple formula in terms of $a,b,c$ for $r_3 - r_1$?

Comment: there is a cubic formula, it is not exactly simple.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html

Comment: Also consider the trigonometric version of the cubic formula.

Comment: There are, however, nice formulas for expressions symmetric (or alternating) in the roots, e.g., $(r_3 - r_2)(r_2 - r_1)(r_1 - r_3)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [lhf's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2264704/75794) indicates, you cannot expect a formula for something independent from $r_2$. Yet there are potentially useful inequalities for the case of real roots.
By [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas) we have
$$(r_2-r_1)^2+(r_3-r_2)^2+(r_3-r_1)^2=2(a^2-3b)$$
and in the case of real roots with $r_1\leq r_2 \leq r_3$, the first two squares sum up to at least half the third square and at most the third square itself, depending on where $r_2$ is. That is,
$$r_3-r_1\in\left[d,\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{3}\,d\right]\quad\text{where}\quad d=\sqrt{a^2-3b}$$
Since $\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{3}\approx 1.16$, that uncertainty might be small enough to be tolerable for some applications.

Comment: As it happens, that uncertainty is small enough for my application. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Every polynomial formula on $a,b,c$ will give a symmetric function of $r_1, r_2, r_3$ and so cannot be $r_3-r_1$.